# detect face aspect ratio

Tags: ios

I am working on a demo in ios where a user takes a photograph from camera or from photo gallery, and then some how determine whether the person is japenese, chinese, asian from the skin color, and shape of eyes. Is there any ios library that can help me to achieve this goal. 
If there is no such library, can anyone guide if it is even physible or what approach should I follow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to look into [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) for any kind of feature detection. From what I understand this framework allows you to detect specific colors shapes etc.. and should help you achieve your goal.

Then as far as any kind of basic face detection goes, you can use Apple's [CIDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreImage/Reference/CIDetector_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Can I crop the eyes using OpenCV ? Using CIDetector, I can find the location of eye and then create an approximate rectangular bound for the eye. My goal is not to crop the rectangular portion within which the eye lies, but to crop the exact bounds for the eye. If this is possible using openCV, can u provide me some link where there have documented for doing such a task? Thanking you in anticipation.

Comment: @Deep2012 I personally haven't used OpenCV but from what I hear it is very powerful, and you could use CIDetector to get the coordinates of the eye in the photo, and CGContext to crop away everything but an area you define around the points for the eyes.